# Toolbar is not visible on Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Firstly I had a Toolbar, then I added a  recycler view but now the toolbar is gone. I have tried everything to display the toolbar but I always failed. Can you tell me how I can get the toolbar back? Thanks in advance.
Here is my Java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private IsAdapter isAdapter;
    private List<Is> isList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        isList = new ArrayList<>();
        isAdapter = new IsAdapter(this, isList);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(1, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(isAdapter);

        prepareIsler();

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);



        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TTT");
        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);


    }
```

Here is the layout code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                />

         <!--   <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" /> -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.neozeka1.dts2.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="info.androidhive.cardview.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You want just one content `View` in a `DrawerLayout`. So, however you mean to arrange things, everything that is not the drawer should all be in one `ViewGroup` above your drawer `<fragment>`.

Comment: @MikeM can you please show with an example? Thank you very much

Comment: Not really, 'cause I can't tell what you're trying to do. If the `RecyclerView` is meant to be the main content, then just move it to inside the outermost `LinearLayout`, below `container_toolbar`, and get rid of the `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`. You can ditch the `container_toolbar` `LinearLayout`, too, if nothing else is going inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this hierarchy.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Main Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Left Drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.findthewayapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Where is `RecyclerView` gone?

Comment: @jason I am just giving the hierarchy `RecycleView` and all other stuff are come in `FrameLayout` or you can use it `RelativeLayout`. I am just giving you `Pattern` as `Mike M.` comment out.

Comment: So, should I add RecycleView inside `FrameLayout`?

Comment: @jason which purpose you used `RecyclerView` can you tell me ??

Comment: In RecyclerView, there are cardviews, and user use these cardviews, such as clicking on their menus or something like that..

Comment: @jason ok then put it inside One thing Make sure in Mind your main Container now is `FrameLayout` in my case you can change it by your requirement.

Comment: When I put recyclerview below toolbar, it worked, thanks!

Comment: @jason glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Put your toolbar widget in AppBar like this -**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**And then - android:below="@+id/appbar  in your recyclerview"**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Should I use a `RelativeLayout` at root? Thanks.